# Need to generate bulk files in Jmeter and upload the files with UUID filename format with || symbol

Tags: csv, jmeter

Required to create dummy files with random data of varying size of less than 1MB.
These dummy files needs to be renamed to UUID format with || symbol specified in the CSV file:

Eg: 6d3a3f2e-ed34-11ea-adc1-0242ac120002||aaa

Jmeter should create the dummy files and rename to 6d3a3f 2e-ed34-11ea-adc1-0242ac120002||aaa and upload the file.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file with random content using JSR223 PreProcessor

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which performs the file upload
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   new File(vars.get('variable_from_csv')).text = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(1, 1024 * 1024)
   ```
3. That's it, the PreProcessor will create the file of random length between 1 byte and 1 megabyte in JMeter's "bin" folder and the file name will come from the CSV

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Added in the code in JSR223 PreProcessor, but getting this error : groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#<init>.Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between: [class java.lang.String]  [class java.net.URI]